# Applying Germany student visa along with spouse visa

Tags: germany, study

I am an Indian Citizen currently living in Bangalore. My husband recently got admission in one of the university of Berlin for MBA and the program starts in Sep 2017. He will be applying for his student visa soon and I have some questions regarding the same.

1) Is it possible that my husband student visa and my spouse dependent visa can be applied together.

2) If not then how long my husband has to stay in Germany before initiating dependent visa for me and how long the process take ?

Will really appreciate some help on the above queries.

Comment: It's a great question but we don't know anything about student visas and spouse visas. It's the job of our sister site, Expats. I have flagged your question so that the higher ups can migrate it for you, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you [accompany your spouse](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/Infoservice/FAQ/Studium/09-Familiennachzug%20Studenten.html?nn=480902) whose visa allows for [application for residence permit for purposes of study](https://www.study-in.de/en/on-arrival/first-steps/registration-and-residence-permit_27238.php), you can apply for your visa at the same time. Since you are not EU or EEA citizens, there will be some additional requirements (sufficient living space, financial self-sufficiency). This may require written confirmation from his university and, generally, that his stay in Germany is expected to exceed a year.

For your [visa application](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/03_Visabestimmungen/Visabestimmungen_node.html), you will also need your original marriage certificate with a certified German translation, and a copy of the letter confirming his enrollment.

If you do not apply jointly, you will need to have a copy of his passport which shows the valid residence permit. And whether you accompany him or join him later, you should bring a certified translation of your marriage certificate, as you will both to [convert your own visa into a long-term residence permit](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/03_Visabestimmungen/Visabestimmungen_node.html) once you arrive in Germany.