# Working in Germany

Tags: germany

I am an Indian Citizen currently living in Mumbai.My partner recently got admission in WHU - Otto Beisheim School of Management for MBA and the program starts in Sep 2019.We plan to get married in either Jan 2020 or August 2020. He will be applying for his student visa soon and I have some questions regarding the same.I have a few questions regarding the same.

1) Is it possible that my boyfriend's student visa and my visa can be applied together?

2) If not then how long my boyfriend has to stay in Germany before initiating dependent visa for me and how long does the process take ?

3) Also, while my boyfriend is studying, is it possible for me to work in Germany? If not, then under what conditions will I be able to work?

Will really appreciate some help on the above queries.

Comment: please have a look at https://www.studying-in-germany.org/bringing-your-family-to-germany-on-a-student-visa/

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to indicate whether you currently live together, and if so, for how long?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/applying-germany-student-visa-along-with-spouse-visa (no answers yet)